# How to making Display Template Work Correctly

Tags: model-view-controller, number-formatting

I am trying to learn MVC. I had a very simple requirement that I wanted to insert commas in number displayed in a table. This is what I have.

**Model**

```
public partial class PACKAGE
{
    public string PACKAGEID { get; set; }
    [UIHint("withcommas")]
    public Nullable<long> FILESIZE { get; set; }
}
```

**Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\withcommas.cshtml**

```
@Model withcommas
@{
    <span>[@Model.ToString("#,##0")]</span>
}
```

I did want to add the sqare brackets around it.

**Views\Home\Packages.cshtml**

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FILESIZE)
```

What I am getting on the display is *"2287097 withcommas [2,287,097];"*
I do not understand why the original number as well as name of the hint is showing up in addition to the formatted number. I do not understand why there is an extra semicolon at the end.